# Unable to convert local timezone to UTC timezone

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, date-fns

I'm attempting to make a calendar on the front end using Fullcalendar. Once a date is clicked it is meant to send a request to the server to see all the available slots for that day. However before the request is sent I want it to convert the users timezone to UTC then send the request and then server side I'll double check if the request was still made in UTC time. When I attempt to convert the date it doesn't change it just shows same timezone.
I'm also using Date-FNS.

After reading some suggestions it said to parse the date before converting it to the UTC timezone so thats what I did.

```
        async handleDateClick(arg)
        {
            console.log(arg.date)
            const parseDate = parseJSON(arg.date)
            const convertToUTCDate = zonedTimeToUtc(parseDate)
            console.log(convertToUTCDate)
        },
```

Before

```
        async handleDateClick(arg)
        {
            console.log(arg.date)
            const convertToUTCDate = zonedTimeToUtc(arg.date)
            console.log(convertToUTCDate)
        },
```

Both console logs report this time... which is GMT+1

```
Mon Sep 05 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)
Mon Sep 05 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)
```

Comment: Try [Date.prototype.toUTCString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString) ---`console.log(arg.date).toUTCString()` to be fair though you should probably use [`Date.prototype.toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString)

Comment: console.log(arg.date.toUTCString()) I did this and it seemed to work, but now the entire calendar is messed up as it goes back an hour which is the day before... I have some thinking to do hahaha, thanks for your help though... I hate dates.

Comment: Yeah, dates, timezones and daylight savings are a nightmare, particularly so in JavaScript

Comment: @phuzi I don't know of any language that handles time zones better than javascript